# Prevent crash by coding

Tags: swift3, crash, plist

I have a problem with two codes. The both codes, end up with the same result, when it received a wrong data or the data is nil, the app crash. I did try few thing as "do{ }catch{" But do not work. I also can not predict a wrong entry from user.

below example of one of the code:

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let array = getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: "LongRange")

       let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "altitude = %@", TextField.text!)
       let Coordinate = NSString(format:"%@",[array.filter {namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}[0]]) as String?
}  
 func getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: String)->(Array<Dictionary<String,String>>){

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "plist")
        var arr : NSArray?
        arr = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)
        return (arr as? Array<Dictionary<String,String>>)!
    } 
    func getDataforFuelConsumption(data:String)->(Array<[String:String]>){
        let array = getSwiftArrayFromPlist(name: "LongRange")
        let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "altitude = %@", data)

        return [array.filter {namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}[0]] //<- Error appear here!!!! "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: I suggest that you set first an exception breakpoint: In Xcode, open the breakpoint navigator in the left pane, tap the + button at the bottom, and select exception breakpoint. When you execute your code, it will stop before it crashes and will probably show you the reason.

Comment: Well in this reason, I do know why. The information the user try to retrieve, do not exist in the play list file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly, you're trying to return just the first element of the array, wrapped in a new array. This seems wrong in itself. If you only want to return one element, why not return one element? But to the question of how to avoid crashing, you need to check for an empty result.

```
let namePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "altitude = %@", data)
let results = array.filter {namePredicate.evaluate(with: $0)}

if let firstResult = results.first {
   return [firstResult]
} else {
   return []
}
```

Comment: It is working good, Thank you very much. For the comment on the array, you have a very good point. I will check that out.